# Why is this throwing an null point exception?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

For some reason whenever I test this, the IDE throws a NullPointerException at line 46 (the for loop that check the array for a name). It seems to work, since it fetches the name and returns it, but then immediately follows with the exception. Can anyone explain? Thanks!

import java.util.*;
class PhoneNumbers {

```
private String name;
private String number;

PhoneNumbers(String n, String numb) {
    this.name = n;
    this.number = numb;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean repeat = true;
    int count = 11;
    PhoneNumbers[] contacts = new PhoneNumbers[30];

    contacts[0] = new PhoneNumbers("Gina", "(847) 342-0912");
    contacts[1] = new PhoneNumbers("Marcia", "(847) 341-2392");
    contacts[2] = new PhoneNumbers("Rita", "(847) 354-0654");
    contacts[3] = new PhoneNumbers("Jennifer", "(414) 234-0912");
    contacts[4] = new PhoneNumbers("Fred", "(414) 435-0434");
    contacts[5] = new PhoneNumbers("Neil", "(608) 123-0914");
    contacts[6] = new PhoneNumbers("Judy", "(608) 123-0312");
    contacts[7] = new PhoneNumbers("Arlene", "(608) 123-0312");
    contacts[9] = new PhoneNumbers("LaWanda", "(920) 787-9813");
    contacts[10] = new PhoneNumbers("Deepak", "(930) 412-0991");

    while (repeat) {
        boolean found = false;

        System.out.print("Enter your friends name: ");
        String nameInput = sc.nextLine();

         if (!nameInput.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){

             for(int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++){
                    if (contacts[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameInput)) {<---Here's where the issue occurs***
                        found = true;
                        System.out.println(contacts[i].getName() + "'s number is " + contacts[i].getNumber());
                }
             }
             if (!found){
                 System.out.println("Enter your friends phone number: ");
                 String num = sc.nextLine();

                 contacts[count + 1] = new PhoneNumbers(nameInput, num);
                 count++;
             }
         }else if (nameInput.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            repeat = false;
        }else if (count == 30){
             repeat = false;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug will answer your question better than anyone else.

Comment: Take a look at java.util.List instead of using arrays as you do. It will help you handling those errors.

Comment: And your loop doesn’t iterate over the whole array as it is iterating while i < count -1 so i < 10 which means that i will never reach 10. You should remove your -1 or replace < by <=.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `contacts[8]` in your initialization, so you will get a `NullPointerException` when trying to access the name of the non-existing contact 8:

```
// ...
contacts[7] = new PhoneNumbers("Arlene", "(608) 123-0312");
contacts[9] = new PhoneNumbers("LaWanda", "(920) 787-9813");
// ...
```

Comment: Wow, feel silly now... thank you!